# Why is dtype being changed in simple pandas array function from int64 to float64?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas data frame. If I check the data-type of the date column by writing

```python
analytic_events.date.dtype
```

I get the result

`dtype('int64')`

And yet if I run this simple array function (which returns the value from the date column in the next row) the type is changed

```python
def duration(analytic_event):
    return analytic_event.date.shift(-1)
duration(analytic_events)
```

thus:

`Name: date, Length: 3373668, dtype: float64`

Why isn't this simple function preserving the type of the column and how would I rewrite it to do so?

Comment: Because `NaN` is be design `float`, it is created by `shift`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By shifting, you've introduced a null spot at the end of the series.  That get's filled in with `np.nan`.  Unfortunately, `np.int64` doesn't have an equivalent null object as does `np.float64`.

#### Alternative 1

Fill with zero

```
analytic_event.date.shift(-1).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

---

#### Alternative 2

Chop of the end

```
pd.Series(analytic_event.date.values[1:], analytic_event.index[:-1], name='date')
```